# Restructure docker persistent volume / mount path

Tags: docker, mount, volumes

I was using the Postgres:11 docker image for a while now until I noticed that next to my persistent volume mount "pg-data" (Destination: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata") there was another unnamed volume listed when doing `docker inspect pgcontainer`, Destination: "/var/lib/postgresql/data":

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "pg-data",
        "Source": "/data/docker/docker/volumes/pg-data/_data",
        "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "z",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    },
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "4d0ab5fd1d81b05f11805f19569e148427194ef465f0d4dc301b200b8308ada6",
        "Source": "/data/docker/docker/volumes/4d0ab5fd1d81b05f11805f19569e148427194ef465f0d4dc301b200b8308ada6/_data",
        "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

After further investigation, it turns out that the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/Dockerfile) itself defines a volume mount path, and I was overriding this with my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  db:
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

volumes:
  pg-data:
  imposm-cache-data:
```

It appears to be a nested volume now. The data is stored in volume `pg-data`, but another (unnamed) volume is always automatically created before it. It works, but this is not ideal and I'd like to fix this.

I can only come up with two solutions:

1. Use another container (e.g. busybox) to mount the pg-data with `--volume` flag and copy to another named volume with subfolder "data", then use the new named volume with changed mount path to `/var/lib/postgresql/data`
2. Another obvious idea would be to clone the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/11/Dockerfile) and create a new one without the volume.

Since that volume has about 100GB of data in it, option 1 will be kind of slow. Option 2 would mean maintaining another Docker image from now on. Both options with caveats. Is there any other approach available to restructure volumes based on a new mount path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just accept the fact of the near-empty anonymous volumes.

Docker gives you fairly few options for manipulating the contents of volumes directly, and the options you list out are pretty much the choices you have without trying to manipulate Docker internals.  Of those two, forking the PostgreSQL image to remove its `VOLUME` seems like a massive ongoing maintenance problem.  So if you have the time and the disk space, the one-time volume copy is better.

Another option you have (and it's probably worth attempting this occasionally) is to stand up a new clean system.  Install Docker on it, and start PostgreSQL with the directory/volume layout you want, but empty.  Now restore this database from backup.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was considering leaving it as is and upgrading the volume setup once we're doing a system reset with `docker system prune` and `docker volume prune`. Luckiliy, this happens once in a while. In a production system that's running over years, however, this wouldn't be an option.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is Dockerfile is creating an **anonymous volume** for your and you are creating another one inside it as a **named volume** with the name pg-data.

You can simply just use a named volume one level above and it should solve your problem.

```
pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: I know, but what if I have data in that **named volume** that I want to keep? Then I'll have to somehow modify the structure inside the named-volume (because postgres expects its data in subfoler `./data/pgdata` and the named volume doesn't contain `pgdata`, as this was the previous mount point.